# Is mass inversely proportional to squared speed of light from relativity theory?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

Relativity says $E=mc^2$ From which we can get, $c^2=E/m$

So speed of light squared is inversely proportional to mass

Comment: Yes, so what is your question?

Comment: $E=mc^2$ only applies to things that are not moving.  The full equation is $E^2=\left(mc_0^2\right)^2+(pc)^2$ with $E$ being the energy, $c$ being the speed of light, $m_0$ being the rest mass, and $p$ being the momentum

Comment: Speed of light squared is what you get when you divide the rest energy to mass. Saying that the *speed of light squared is inversely proportional to mass* is meaningless. $c^2$ is a proportionality factor that allows to transform between mass and rest energy.

Comment: We say A is proportional to B to evidentiate that when B increases, A also increases. For example: kinetic energy is proportional to velocity.

Comment: @AndreiGeanta The correct terms are rest mass, and energy.

Comment: @AndersGustafson, It is redundant to say rest mass. Mass is the difference between energy squared and momentum squared. I said [rest energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass#Rest_energy), which by the way is a term that is being used, to evidentiate that the formula is valid only when the object is at rest.

Comment: Except that your formula is derived from the assumption that c is a constant. You can vary the mass by an amount of energy equal to delta m c^2

Comment: This is kind of like saying $1=\frac{p}{mv}$, so $1$ is inversely proportional to velocity.

Answer (score 1):

> So speed of light squared is inversely proportional to mass

$c$ is a universal *constant*, the *invariant* speed, while neither $E$ and $m$ are.

Your reasoning is as incorrect as this reasoning is:

> Einstein says $E = h\nu$ from which we get $h = \frac{E}{\nu}$, so
>   Planck's constant $h$ is inversely proportional to frequency